Stone–Weierstrass theorem for topological fields
It was showed in "The Stone–Weierstrass Theorem for valuable fields" that the Stone–Weierstrass theorem holds for any topological field whose topology comes from an absolute value or a Krull valuation (these are exactly the fields with Type V topologies).
Since any topological field is a uniform space, given a compact Hausdorff space $X$ the algebra of continuous functions $C(X,F)$ can be endowed with the uniform convergence topology (which is also the compact–open topology).
With this in mind, we say that a topological field $F$ (except for $\mathbb{C}$) satisfies the Stone–Weierstrass theorem if for all compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ if $A\subset C(X,F)$ is a subalgebra which contains the constant functions and separates points, then $A$ is uniformly dense (in the sense above).
Are there any examples of topological fields satisfying this theorem outside the metric cases? Is there a characterization of when a field satisfies this theorem?

"The Stone-Weierstrass Theorem for valuable fields": can you please provide a full citation for this work? If you edit your question, there is a Cite button you can use.

Perhaps also include a more complete statement.
